# Improving the performance of IEnumerable.ToDictionary()

Tags: .net, performance, linq, dictionary, ienumerable

**Background**

I read an XML file, and load a huge (1 million) collection of `Person`s into memory. This collection is `IEnumerable(Of Person)`.

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Age As Int
End Class
```

**What I have**

I want to categorize this collection by `FirstName`, so I write this Linq query:

```
Dim groupedCollection = From p 
                         In Persons 
                        Group By p.FirstName
                         Into PersonsWithSameName = Group
```

Now I want to convert this `groupedCollection` to a `Dictionary`. So I write this:

```
Dim myPersonDictionary = groupedCollection.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.FirstName, 
                                                        Function(x) x.PersonsWithSameName)
```

**The problem**

The problem is that the performance of `.ToDictionary` function is terrible for such a big collection. I'm not sure, but I think it's because it first enumerates my original collection, as I leave all collections as `IEnumerable` from the begining to the end, except for the cases that I need an enumeration.

I've read [here](http://code-ninja.org/blog/2014/07/24/entity-framework-never-call-groupby-todictionary/) that it's not a good idea to use `Group By` and `.ToDictionary` together. However, I don't see a difference when I use the suggested appraoch (so, first executing a `Select` on my `groupedCollection`).

**What I want to Achiev** is a `Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable(Of Person))` (or another data structure that I can use in a similar way).

My **Question** is, how I can get this `Dictionary` in a better way (in terms of performance).

Comment: Is it possible for you to take list ?

Comment: You can user parallel processing by using AsParallel() with IEnumerable(Of Person)

Comment: The link you provided in the question relates to Entity Framework calls (which use `IQueryable<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>`). The advice there does not relate to your code at all.

Comment: Now, have you separated the time required to load the XML from the time that the query takes?

Comment: @GaurangDave No using a list is not an option, as I would have a similar problem in `.ToList` operation.

Comment: @GaurangDave About `AsParallel()`, where should I use it? I just tried 2 options:  1. `(From p In Persons.AsParallel() ..).ToDictionary()`, 2.  `(From p ... Into PersonsWithSameName = Group).AsParallel().ToDictionary()`

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for the hint about Entitty Framework :) about separating the time: this is correct that loading this big file also takes a log time, however, what I _see_ the problem is by executing this line.

Comment: @Yvonnila meanwhile check this https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3337, someone has reported same report as well. You might get something

Comment: @Yvonnila - How have you seen that? Please show us your benchmark code.

Comment: @Yvonnila AsParallerl() is part of plinq. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq

Comment: @Enigmativity This is how I have seen it:
- **Loading the file:** _3.820 ms_  
- **Reading the objects from the file** (including a conversion here): _<1 ms_ as this isn't executed here yet. This returns my original collection as an IEnumerable(Of Person)  
- **Grouping and converting to dictionary**: _9.815 ms_ (my problem)

Comment: @GaurangDave thanks for the link, I'll read it :)

Comment: @Yvonnila - That doesn't sound possible. Loading an XML file with 1,000,000 elements in 3.820 ms. Please post your code so that we can see your issue.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: What was the result of profiling your code?  (Never, ever, ever try to improve performance without profiling your code unless there is a blindingly obvious algorithmic problem.)

Comment: @Yvonnila I am not sure how you are getting `IEnumerable(Of Person)` when loading XML, but if it is true, then you aren't loading the file until you execute the `ToDictionary`, because an `IEnumerable` is a promise of a collection, and that takes milliseconds to create. Until you do something that enumerates the collection, you haven't executed any real processing code. Try putting in `var temp = p.Count();` and see how long that takes to run.

Comment: @NetMage thanks for your comment, that is exactly my problem. What I want is finding a way to prevent the original collection from being enumerated. My resulting dictionary has only 4 elements (with big collections as values), and I don't need an enumeration on these values. _My guess_ is that these values get enumerated. I'm not sure if I'm right, though.

Comment: @Craig I think I'd need to work on that a bit, to be able to answer your question.

Comment: If you want to know more about how Group By works under the hood, see https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby/ (and that series in general is fabulous for getting a real understanding of what Linq does).

Comment: @Craig Oh thanks! I will read the articles.

Comment: @Yvonnila Think about how group by must work - how will it group together based on the elements without actually reading the elements? If you don't enumerate the collection, you can't compute an answer, and you won't have read in the file, so you can't create the dictionary. If you want to delay enumeration until later, you would need to avoid the `ToDictionary`.

Comment: @NetMage yeah I really had missed this! Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that your problem is when you load the XML.

Here's an example that shows why:

```
var rnd = new Random();

Func<string> createName =
    () => new string(
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, 3)
            .Select(n => (char)(rnd.Next(0, 26) + 'a'))
            .ToArray());

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var persons =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 1000000)
        .Select(x => new { FirstName = createName(), LastName = createName() })
        .ToArray();

var el1 = sw.Elapsed;

var grouped = persons.GroupBy(p => p.FirstName, p => p.LastName).ToArray();

var el2 = sw.Elapsed;

var dictionary = grouped.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p);

var el3 = sw.Elapsed;

Console.WriteLine(el1.TotalMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine(el2.Subtract(el1).TotalMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine(el3.Subtract(el2).TotalMilliseconds);
```

When I run this code I get an output like this:

```
1095.7095
266.2265
1.624
```

So it's taking 1095.7095 milliseconds to create the objects. It then takes 266.2265 to group them by first name. And finally it takes only 1.624 milliseconds to create the dictionary.

If you have a performance issue then it's not in the grouping or the creation of the dictionary. Otherwise you need to post your code and show us how you determined where the issue is.